# Angular2 - Firefox not detectChanges but Chrome does

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angular, firefox

I have the following code that works in Chrome without `this.cdr.detectChanges();` (cdr: `ChangeDetectorRef`)

```
this.channelService.sub(id)
  .subscribe(
    (x: ChannelEvent) => {
      console.log("event received");
      switch (x.Name) {
        case ChannelEventType.onUpdateStatus:
          {
            this.updateStatus();
            console.log("status updated to " + x.Data.Status);
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
          }
      }
    },
    (error: any) => {
      console.warn("Attempt to join channel failed!", error);
    }
  );
```

But in Firefox I have to call detect changes for `signalR` subscription on events. Please give some ideas what could cause a problem with Firefox to apply changes for view when view model changed?